# Use form value for if-clause in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I wish to show a bunch of messages depending on your location, options are "close by" (value="close") and "far" (value="far")

I made a form for this in my .cshtml file

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <label for="distance">Show people:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="distance" value="Far" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();"/> All
        <input type="radio" name="distance" value="Close" onClick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();" /> Close by
    </div>
</form>
```

Then I have the options for showing it that looks like this

```
@if form1.radio == "far" //sort of pseudo code :)

@foreach(var message in  Model.Messages)
else 
@foreach (var message in Model.Messages.Skip(Math.Max(0, Model.Messages.Count() - 12))) 
{
do some stuff
}
```

Never mind syntax errors in the end of this code, my problem is to pick up the value of "distance".

Have written the following in the viewmodel

```
public string Distance { get; set; }
```

and in the controller in an actionresult

```
viewModel.Distance = distance;
```

but that doesn't seem valid

Thank you in advance

Comment: probably the foreach:es don't make any sense, i stripped them of longitude and latitude values for this example

Comment: If your wanting to display items based on which radio button the user selects in the view, then you need to use javascript to respond to client side events.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using ASP.net MVC helpers and your view model within the view for compile time checking, plus it's what asp MVC is for.

```
@model FooViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Method", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Distance)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => Model.Far)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => Model.Close)

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Method(FooViewModel fooModel)
{
    if (fooModel.Far){
       ViewData["Messages"] = MyMessageListHere;
    }
    else if (fooModel.Close){
       ViewData["Messages"] = MyMessageListHere;
    }

    return View();
}
```

and then in the view that is returned just do:

```
@foreach (var message in (List<string>)ViewData["Messages"])
{
    Html.DisplayFor(x => message);
}
```

Untested code, but hopefully you get the idea. You should also be seperating your JS from html, `onClick="..."` isn't a good idea. Here you also don't even need Js.

Comment: Thank you, yes I know about the helpers, some other guys started this project and I'm picking up where they left it. They used these oldfashioned forms so I did too... (the onclick is my own quick and dirty idea though) Let's see if I can make this work

Comment: But then again, the onclick javascript was simply for doing a submit without a button, I see now that your exampel has a button

Comment: @gomummy If you do not want a button which is fine then you should separate that onClick code into a separate JS file.

I presume you just had it for testing though judging by your previous comment. Thought I had better mention it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input, Martin and also Stephen

One skilled person was back at work today, so I now know I needed to write this in the controller

```
 viewModel.Distance = HttpContext.Request.Form["distance"];
```

And then the pseudo code I wrote in the view needed to be written

```
@if (Model.Distance == "Far")    
{
  //adding the rest for you here
  @foreach(var message in  Model.Messages)
  {
    do some stuff 
  }
  else 
  @foreach (var message in Model.Messages.Skip(Math.Max(0, Model.Messages.Count() - 12))) 
  {
    do some stuff
  }
}
```

What I wrote in the viewmodel was correct. Hope this will help someone else.

Some comments:

Martin, in your first code part you seemed to mix different code areas, first the view, I haven't seen forms written elsewhere? Then the model, I haven't seen much yet but I haven't seen if-clauses in model?

I am still grateful for your effort to help me!

Stephen, might be I will do this again in javascript, cause it really shouldn't  be reloading the page, as the messages are also going to be put on a google map, so next challenge is to get multiple markers on the map using javascript (it is working showing marker for my current position to start with)

Thank you for your input!